# Nullstellensatz proof: we have an isomorphism $\phi$ between al. closed $F$ and $F[x_1, ..., x_n]/m$. Why do we have $x_i - \phi^{-1}(x_i+m) \in m$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to prove the weak Nullstellensatz (every maximal ideal has the form $(x_1 - a_1, \dots, x_n - a_n)$), and a key step of the argument is as follows:

We have $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. From Zariski's lemma, we obtain that $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$ is an algebraic extension of $k$, which implies the field extension $\phi: k \to k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\mathfrak m$ is an isomorphism. But multiple authors argue that, from this isomorphism, we obtain $x_i - \phi^{-1}(x_i+\mathfrak m) \in \mathfrak m$. However, this is not at all clear to me, and I've attempted to reconstruct the authors' argument as follows: the surjectivity of our isomorphism must give us some $a_i$ such that $\phi(a_i) = x_i + \mathfrak m$, and the definition of our isomorphism gives us that $\phi(a_i) = a_i + \mathfrak m$. We get our desired result from $\phi(a_i)=x_i + \mathfrak m = a_i + \mathfrak m$.

But why does the fact our field extension $\phi:k \to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$ is an isomorphism imply we must have $\phi(a_i) = a_i + \mathfrak m$? A field homomorphism is injective, but why must this particular injection be the one that must be implied, aren't there other explicit homomorphisms that could have the same codomain? And if I'm misunderstanding the line of argument, then where does the result $x_i - \phi^{-1}(x_i+\mathfrak m) \in \mathfrak m$ come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $\phi$ is not arbitrary but rather the composition of the inclusion $k \to k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ as constant polynomials and the tautological quotient map $k[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/\mathfrak{m}$ that takes $f \mapsto f + \mathfrak{m}$. So $\phi(a) = a + \mathfrak{m}$ for $a \in k$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! Should we therefore first define this map, and only afterwards invoke Zariski's lemma, in order to guarantee that it is surjective?

Comment: @shintuku Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is $\phi^{-1}(f(x_1,...,x_n)) = f(a_1,...,a_n)$ because if $f(a_1,..a_n) = g(a_1,...a_n) \implies (f-g)(a_1,..,a_n)) = 0 \implies f-g \in M = \langle\{x_i-a_i : i \in [n]\}\rangle$.

So what you need to prove is by $f(a_1,...,a_n) = 0 \iff f \in \langle\{x_i-a_i : i \in [n]\}\rangle$. This can be proved by dividing $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ by $x_1-a_1$ repeatedly and make sure degree of $x_1$ in the reminder is $0$  and then dividing the reminder by $x_2 - a_2$ and so on till $x_n-a_n$ and argue that all previous quotient terms are multiple of $x_j-a_j$ for $j \leq n$ and hence are $0$ when evaluated at $a_1,a_2,..,a_{n}$. So reminder which is a constant is also $0$ as degree of any $x_j$ is $0$, since $f(a_1,...,a_n) = 0$. So $f(a_1,...,a_n) \implies f \in M$. The other direction is obvious.

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` for angled brackets: compare $\langle x-a_i\rangle$ versus $<x-a_i>$.

Comment: done. Thanks !!!